# Does Apollo cache the queries made from a Query component?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have one `Query` component that retrieves data from a GraphQL server and everything works great.

There's a stateless child component I'm currently passing props to, and I would like to make it propless by setting it to read data from the local Apollo cache (the child component can never be loaded prior to the parent component).

I'm getting an error though. I understand from the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching#readquery) that the `readQuery` method fails if there's nothing in the cache, but that's what confuses me: the data **should** be in the cache as it's loaded before in the parent component. Or is it not?

Here's the source code:

- [Parent Component](https://gist.github.com/PaulRBerg/fbce504b2bed835501b69bcef57991ff)
- [Child Component](https://gist.github.com/PaulRBerg/4d62f09f9f1de04ad2cfba27440e442c)
- [Queries](https://gist.github.com/PaulRBerg/e4db3a4f06a009d8ae20086fdc925198)

Comment: details, code, queries, types, no `id` fields defined ...

Comment: We would need more context to identify potential reasons for this behavior. Please include the relevant code (i.e. both components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `readQuery` simply reads from the cache once, which is almost never what you want. The `Query` component subscribes to changes in the cache and will trigger a network request on a cache-miss (assuming you're using the default `cache-first` [fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy)). You can safely utilize multiple `Query` components across your app for the same query -- as long as they use the same `variables`, rendering multiple `Query` components will only result in a single request to your server.

`readQuery` should only be used inside `update` functions when you need to read and then update a part of the cache -- don't use it to provide data to your components. If you only want to read from cache, there's a `cache-only` policy you can use, but again, this is rarely needed because Apollo is smart enough to know when a query is in flight.